# Functions, object and generators

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to simulate the way a generator works by returning  different values of `i` when it is called. Function a works but function a1 gives me the same value of `i` every time I call it.

why doesn't a1 works ??

```js
function a () {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      return i++;
    }
  }
}
let b = a();
console.log(b.next()); //output 0
console.log(b.next()); // output 1
console.log(b.next()); // output 2
```

```js
function a1 () {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    next: i++
  }
}
let b1 = a1();
console.log(b1.next); //output 0
console.log(b1.next); //output 0
console.log(b1.next); //output 0
```

Comment: because `b1` is static: it's calculated only once when `a1()` is called and from there its value remains the same.

Comment: When you run a function it *executes some code*. So, in the first snippet calling `next()` will *execute* the code and thus change `i`. In the second snippet, `i++` is assigned a single time and each call to `b1.next` just returns that initially assigned value.

Comment: If you want to make accessing a property run a function, define a getter.

Comment: The question is actually about **closures** in javascript and how returned functions can use internal context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b1.next` is not a function. It's just an object property that holds a static value. `i++` was calculated and assigned to the property at the time the object was created.

If you want to make it act like a function, define a getter.

```js
function a1 () {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    get next() { return i++; }
  }
}
let b1 = a1();
console.log(b1.next); //output 0
console.log(b1.next); //output 1
console.log(b1.next); //output 2
```

Comment: this code return the same value of i everytime. How is it different from function above`` ` function a() {
  let i = 5;
  return i++;
}```

Comment: No it doesn't. Click "Run Code Snippet"

Comment: @Bamar i mean this code **function a() { let i = 5; return i++; }** returns the same value of i

Comment: Every time you call the function you re-initialize `i` to `5`.

Comment: You need to declare and initialize the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a1` function returns just an object `{next: 0}` because `i++` expression is calculated only once, at the moment of calling `a1()`.

In turn, the first `a` function returns object with method `next` which you then can execute as many times as you need.